# How to apply attribute for text in `UITextView` without setting `attributedText` property?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm working on editor with syntax highlighting. After each character typed i should parse the text and highlight it. The problem is that if i create `NSAttributedString` instance and do `UITextViewinstance.attributedText = newAttrStr` i have `textViewDidChange:` event and some reinits in UITextView and UITextStorage behind the scene.

How to apply attribute for text in `UITextView` without setting `attributedText` property?

Can i use `NSMutableAttributeString` for example and add/remove attributes (i believe it works if UITextView does not copy NSAttributedString instance only but it's `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText`)? Any another approach?

Comment: I suggest you to subclass `UITextView` and override methods to add features in it. `NSMutableAttributeString` is the answer to use attributed text.

Comment: How does it solve my problem?